# What's the correct forum to ask end-user-questions concerning WhatsApp on Android?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

The title kind of says it all. I am looking for a professionally moderated forum concerned with end-user-questions on android apps.

I did an extensive search on Android-Forums, but all I found was discussion boards with low quality posts concerning technical knowledge.

Comment: ..and I want someone else to find one for me :(

Comment: "I dont want you to find it for me... just post it here so i can get to it without searching for it"..... feels paradoxical a bit

Comment: Whether I have to search for it, or already know the answer, isn't the point here. At all. The point is that you should try to do what you can to answer your own question. This here reeks of "I can't be bothered to search so someone give me the answer". Whoever has the abswer has to have searched for it at some point (no one is born with innate knowledge of Stack)....

Comment: Two things: 1) how are we supposed to guess what research you have done? The title or 3 lines of your question dont indicate any of that research. And 2) the goal of Stack is to be a high level repo of knowledge with low noise to signal ratio. The question should be for more than just you. It should be useful to anyone looking for the same thing. To achieve that goal, stack has guidelines about doing prior research and showing your work

Comment: Do you go to the hardware store to ask about the best place to eat lunch? Site recommendations on MSO are still for **programming-related** inquiry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you mean a Stack Exchange site. (Insert obligatory "Stack Exchange is not a forum" rant here.)

If the question is about specific apps on Android, then [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) is the place to go. You mentioned WhatsApp, they have a [tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-messenger) for questions about WhatsApp.

If the question is about end user experience, something you're developing, then [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com) is the place you're looking for.

In general: there is a [canonical question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/168333) about where to ask computer questions - although it doesn't mention Android Enthusiasts or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com), our Apple Stack Exchange.
And the [All sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) list can show you some sites you never even knew existed. Did you know that we have a separate site for [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com)?

As always, check the Help Center of these sites to see if your question is on-topic there, before you post there.